# Automatic updates for Oracle Java Runtime on CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, packages, repository

I'm a longtime user of Ubuntu and use webupd8 repository to install and automatically update my Oracle JRE on Ubuntu.

Is there something similar that enables me to do the same on CentOS 7 (or RHEL)?

I would like to have the runtime updated whenever other updates are installed and this should run silently.

Comment: The default java-openjdk gets updated. No repo for Oracle JRE , AFAIK. .....  The CentOS 5 identical 'Scientific Linux SL5' had Sun java in the repo. Ended with `jdk-1.6.0_41` .( Stopped after Oracle bought Sun Microsystems.) - Today : No CentOS compatible Oracle java repo any more. - Available RPMS : Oracle and PCLinuxOS ('apt for rpm' repo) only. -